# Changing chart types with vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there i would like to use vba to change a pie chart to a bar chart and vice versa . I have used this code from a similar question but it does not seem to work. It gives me a system error message saying "parameter not found". When i run it from the developer itself,it gives me a run time error 5. Need help to debug this or a code to help change chart types.Thank you. Here is the code:

```
Sub ApplyPieChart()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart Title").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
End Sub

Sub ApplyBarChart()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart Title").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code runs without error for me. Check the name of the chart. Most likely it is not "Chart Title" but something like "Chart 1", unless you changed it.

[image]